# How do I re-open nodejs server info

Tags: node.js

For some reason I often notice after having my terminal open for a while, I can't see the output from my nodejs server anymore. I know it's running, though. How do I re-open the node output info? (By output info, I mean "console.log" in nodejs code. I'm running on linux.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: The question is not dependent on code, except console.log like I mentioned. So if you like:  console.log("hello"); does not output anymore

Comment: Q: You're saying that you have a NodeJS app that writes stuff to your Linux terminal window using console.log() ... and it eventually *STOPS* writing to the terminal?  For no reason?  On the face of it, that doesn't make sense.  Please elaborate.

Comment: @paulsm4 - That's not what I'm saying. What I am saying is that I can no longer see the output. I believe that it still is outputting, but for some reason I stop seeing it on the terminal after a certain point. jatin Mehrotra. Yes, I am using nodemon.

Comment: That's even less likely.  If something is *written* to your terminal window, then it should *appear* in your  terminal window.  Do you have any justification for this "belief" that "it is still outputting"?  Regardless: "nodemon" is an interesting thought.  What happens if you disable it?

Comment: Yes. When I open up active ports I can see my node server running on a port still. If I try to run my node server again, it won't run because the port is already being used. I have an action I do to console.log on my server, and am performing that action which should output a lot, but nothing. I think you misunderstand. I think I performed the action of ctrl c to go back to the terminal section where you can go into directories/etc, and of course I can't see output because I'm not in the server output anymore. My question is how to get back.

Comment: Can you add your `nodemon` command? I would guess you are running scripts that run the process rather than the node process directly so nodemon doesn't have direct control. There could possibly be an issue in your app stopping it from exiting.

Comment: my exact command is "nodemon connect_socket.js &"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to this, my research conclusion is that it's an artifact of nodemon that exists. You have to physically go into the port and kill it, which I've spent an enormous amount of time doing. Not very helpful if you were running this in production and you couldn't see output anymore. But it is what it is.

Comment: This is usually indicative of issues with how the app is being run, or the app itself. If you include the details of what you're running and your app then it can probably be solved.  nodemon is a development tool, not really for production use.

Comment: I can tell you that I am running nodejs primarily with socket.io with users connecting and disconnecting. I am using express. It's an https server that uses ssl. Besides that, I can't think of anything else that would be relevent